# Determining gaps in polylines and identifying continuing sections?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mapinfo, line

Is there a relatively quick way to identify where gaps < a certain size are present between polyline? E.g. would there be an easy way to join line likes the ones in the below image if the gap was <10m?

[image]

I have access to ArcMap, MapInfo and QGIS.

Comment: Do the lines have a unique identifier?  You may be able to use topology rules, specifically Rule: Must Be Single Part.

Comment: Each line is part of a named road sections, one section may have multiple, but I don't need any identifiers for the final result as I am combining all data and disaggregating it, as it will be queried against another road network using spatial queries

Comment: Wasn't clear on your statement "one section may have multiple". Can you look for multiple features per some attribute value to indicate gaps (although this would not be filtered by <10m)?

Answer (score 3):

In ArcGIS, you may want to try [Extend Line (Editing)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000004000000).  In the tool you can specify the extend length to a tolerance of 10m.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately my work doesn't have that feature licensed :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how quick this (untested) ArcMap solution would be, but...also not sure of your licensing limitations on function access.

Could run [`MultipartToSinglepart_management`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#/Multipart_To_Singlepart/00170000003r000000/), [`GenerateNearTable`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#/Generate_Near_Table/00080000001n000000/) on the result, and filter on distance. You might have to use `JoinField` or something on the singlepart result to bring over whatever attribute field you're using to unify multipart features.

Could probably use `Buffer` or something similar in lieu of `GenerateNearTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Alan,

If you have MapInfo Professional 12.0, have a look at the new PolyBuilder tool that has been added to the Tool Manager